# BGI Error:Graphics not initialised(use initgraph)...in DOSBOX...Win 7

Tags: c, dosbox, bgi

I gave the location of bgi folder in my C drive as below:

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TurboC++\\Disk\\TurboC3\\BGI");
```

The program compiles without any error but while running nothing appears...

When I press Alt+F5 I found this error. How to resolve this?

Comment: i am not mounting it so only it doesn't worked...mount E: C:\\TurboC++\\Disk\\TurboC3\\ then type E: then cd bin then type tc and hit enter in the program change to E:\\BGI...it worked...

Answer (score 5):

**I hope this helps:**

Now, as we know the BGI folder is usually in the following path,

*C:\TurboC++\disk\TurboC3\BGI*

BGI is inside the folder "TurboC3" and NOT "TC".

So the code you need to put in your program is as follows,

```
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TurboC3\\BGI");
```

Answer (score 0):

After declaring variable.

You have to write the following code in your program.

```
initgraph(&gd , &gm ,"C:\\TurboC++\\BGI");
```